# Problem with NVIDIA FX5700 in Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, nouveau

I've decided to upgrade Kubuntu in my old computer. I made a clean installation of Kubuntu 16.10. The system is working, but I cannot change the resolution of my graphics card. Since I've read in many posts that privative drivers of NVIDIA don't cover my old graphics card, I'm using the nouveau driver and the DVI port. The maximum resolution that I've got was 1024x768. My screen could get better resolution, since it is an Acer K242HL. I would like to have a 1920x1080 screen resolution. I also installed the lubuntu-desktop package. Any ideas? How can I get a better resolution by using nouveau driver?

I copy at the end the output of xrandr and lspci.

Thank you for your help and advices.

```
   javier@javier-D1675:~$ xrandr
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
    default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
       1024x768      76.00* 

    The output of xrandr -props | edid-decode is:
javier@javier-D1675:~$ xrandr --props | edid-decode 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Extracted contents:
header:          53 63 72 65 65 6e 20 30
serial number:   3a 20 6d 69 6e 69 6d 75 6d 20
version:         31 30
basic params:    32 34 20 78 20
chroma info:     37 36 38 2c 20 63 75 72 72 65
established:     6e 74 20
standard:        31 30 32 34 20 78 20 37 36 38 2c 20 6d 61 78 69
descriptor 1:    6d 75 6d 20 31 30 32 34 20 78 20 37 36 38 0a 64 65 66
descriptor 2:    61 75 6c 74 20 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 65 64 20 31 30 32
descriptor 3:    34 78 37 36 38 2b 30 2b 30 20 30 6d 6d 20 78 20 30 6d
descriptor 4:    6d 0a 20 20 20 31 30 32 34 78 37 36 38 20 20 20 20 20
extensions:      20
checksum:        37

No header found
Manufacturer: NQ@ Model 696d Serial Number 1970104686
EDID version: 49.48
Analog display, Input voltage level: 0.714/0.286 V
Configurable signal levels
Sync: SyncOnGreen 
Maximum image size: 52 cm x 32 cm
Gamma: 2.20
DPMS levels: Off
Monochrome or grayscale display
Established timings supported:
  720x400@88Hz
  640x480@60Hz
  640x480@72Hz
  640x480@75Hz
  800x600@56Hz
  800x600@75Hz
  832x624@75Hz
  1280x768@87Hz
  1024x768@70Hz
Standard timings supported:
  640x640@108Hz
  648x648@112Hz
  504x378@116Hz
  504x504@115Hz
  680x680@116Hz
  600x600@92Hz
  1120x840@93Hz
  1208x906@101Hz
Detailed mode: Clock 300.610 MHz, 54 mm x 2616 mm
                877  909 1797 1165 hborder 100
                816  834  882 1890 vborder 101
               +hsync +vsync analog composite four way interleaved
Detailed mode: Clock 300.490 MHz, 613 mm x 100 mm
                620  986 1855  736 hborder 49
               1635 1657 1660 5330 vborder 48
               +hsync -vsync digital composite field sequential L/R
Detailed mode: Clock 307.720 MHz, 1901 mm x 2080 mm
                823 1127 1671 2925 hborder 32
                555  606  622 3419 vborder 48
               -hsync +vsync bipolar analog composite side by side interleaved
Detailed mode: Clock 26.690 MHz, 568 mm x 32 mm
                544  596 1484  576 hborder 32
                817  836  875 1377 vborder 32
               -hsync -vsync analog composite field sequential L/R
Has 32 extension blocks
Checksum: 0x37 (should be 0x1f)
EDID block does not conform at all!
    Block has broken checksum
    Bad year of manufacture
    Bad week of manufacture
    Manufacturer name field contains garbage

lspci give me the following:
javier@javier-D1675:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 645xx (rev 50)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-sis
    Kernel modules: sis_agp

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=68
    Memory behind bridge: d5000000-d5ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: e0000000-efffffff
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS963 [MuTIOL Media IO] LPC Controller (rev 14)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:02.1 SMBus: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS961/2/3 SMBus controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at 8100 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: sis96x_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_sis96x

00:02.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] FireWire Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions FireWire Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 11
    Memory at d4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at c0000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci

00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller (prog-if 80 [Master])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions 5513 IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 128, IRQ 9
    [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: pata_sis
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi

00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions USB 1.1 Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 9
    Memory at d4001000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions USB 1.1 Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 11
    Memory at d4002000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:03.2 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions USB 1.1 Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 10
    Memory at d4003000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:03.3 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions USB 2.0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 9
    Memory at d4004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:06.0 Ethernet controller: ADMtek NC100 Network Everywhere Fast Ethernet 10/100 (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions Scenic N300 ADMtek AN983 10/100 Mbps PCI Adapter
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at d4005000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at c0020000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: tulip
    Kernel modules: tulip

00:0c.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs CA0106/CA0111 [SB Live!/Audigy/X-Fi Series]
    Subsystem: Creative Labs SB0570 [SB Audigy SE]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 5
    I/O ports at 1400 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_ca0106
    Kernel modules: snd_ca0106

00:0e.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7134/SAA7135HL Video Broadcast Decoder (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Pinnacle Systems Inc. PCTV Stereo
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 254, IRQ 11
    Memory at d4005400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: saa7134
    Kernel modules: saa7134

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV36 [GeForce FX 5700VE] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: LeadTek Research Inc. NV36 [GeForce FX 5700VE]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 9
    Memory at d5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```